# Error: Cannot transfer an MS Shipped object when consolidate PWA databases

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-project-server-2013, project-web-access

I've tried to upgrade my project server 2010 to 2013. But when I consolidate the databases, I always get error message: **Cannot transfer an MS Shipped object.**

**Here is my command:**
PS C:\Users\gita_p> Convertto-SPProjectDatabase -WebApplication -Db
server bedugul -ArchiveDbname ProjectServer_Archive_New_2013 -DraftDbname Projec
tServer_Draft_New_2013 -PublishedDbname ProjectServer_Published_new_2013 -Report
ingDbname ProjectServer_Reporting_New_2013 -ProjectServiceDbname ProjectServer_S
erviceDB_2013
WARNING: Converting the reporting, published, archive, and draft databases into
 a single Project Database will make it so they can no longer be attached to
Project Server 2010. Before continuing make sure you have a backup copy of
these databases.

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "ConvertTo-SPProjectDatabase" on target
"ProjectServer_ServiceDB_2013".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):

**And here is the Error:**
Convertto-SPProjectDatabase : Cannot transfer an MS Shipped object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Convertto-SPProjectDatabase -WebApplication  -Dbserver bedugul
-Arch ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Offic...baseImpleme
   ntor:ConvertToProjec...baseImplementor) [ConvertTo-SPProjectDatabase], Sql
  Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Cmdlet.PSCmdletC
   onvertToProjectServiceDatabase

anyone can help me?

thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question is a bit older, but as it seems to be the only documented occurence of this error I try to answer it here in case someone else might get this problem.
The reason is probably that there exists a table "dtproperties" in the system tables of at least one of the 4 Project Server 2010 databases. This is treated unproperly by the upgrade procedure. 
The table is related to database diagrams and not needed.
Just delete this table and it will work. To be on the safe side, delete the table only from the copied databases that you use for the migration.
Kind regards
Christoph Muelder